# Specifying relative paths from `RequireJs`

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have the `baseUrl` in a RequireJs based application set to `/angular`. **Sometimes I'd like to set the path relative to the base, other times I'd like to set it relative to the current directory.**

I'm very new to RequireJs and very confused.

This is what I have now:

```
require([
    'require',
    'angular',
    'module/draft/draftDisplay'// module that I want relative to baseUrl
], function(requireLocal, angular) {

requireLocal('./autoSave'); // Modules that I want relative to current url
requireLocal('./module');
```

Which creates this error: `Error: Module name "autoSave" has not been loaded yet for context: _`

As I said before, I can't get a good handle on how RequireJs works. Some things I don't understand are:

1) When does RequireJs use the baseUrl and when does it use the current directory

2) What's the difference between a module ID and its path?

3) Does the way previous modules are specified in the `require([...],..` array affect how subsequent ones are resolved (which seemed to be the case when I tinkered)

If you could include those things in your answer, that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) When does RequireJs use the baseUrl and when does it use the current directory

Always `baseUrl`, except when the module name is prefixed by `./` or `../`, in which case it uses the directory of the module that requires the other.

> 2) What's the difference between a module ID and its path?

The path includes the `baseUrl`. E.g. could be something like `scripts/vendor/angular/angular.js`. The module id does not include the `baseUrl` or the suffix, e.g. for `baseUrl: 'scripts'`, the module id above would be `vendor/angular/angular`.

> 3) Does the way previous modules are specified in the `require([...],..` array affect how subsequent ones are resolved (which seemed to be the case when I tinkered)

No.

---

Your error is caused from using the synchronous version of `require` for modules that are not loaded. Use the asynchronous version instead; something like:

```
requireLocal(['./autoSave', './module'], function(autosave, module) {
    // here autosave and module are loaded
});
// BEWARE: Here neither autosave nor module are loaded
```

But are you sure you want the inner require? From the information you provide, pulling the requirements in the outer require would probably suffice, i.e.

```
require(['require','angular','module/draft/draftDisplay','./autoSave','./module'],...)
```

---

Also, the import called `'module'` has special meaning in require; it contains information about the *current* module; If you are literally using `'./module'` it will be quite different than `'module'` (the first looks for a `module.js` file in the same directory as this file, the second provides information about this module).